# Что такое "Service может быть убит" (Android)

Tags: java, android, service

Если системе не хватает памяти она может убить сервис.

Вопрос: вместе с сервисом умирают и все переменные, которые были инициализированы внутри него?

А если сервис в режиме startForeground, может ли это гарантировать что все экземляры будут продолжать жить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Вопрос:* вместе с сервисом умирают и все переменные, которые были инициализированы внутри него?

*Ответ:* да.

*Вопрос:* А если сервис в режиме startForeground, может ли это гарантировать, что все экземпляры будут продолжать жить?

*Ответ:* Нет, сервис может быть убит и в этом случае, при крайне критической нехватке памяти.

Comment: Как я понимаю, Foreground убивается в одну из самых последних очередей.  И если уж его убили, то мы сделали все что могли?)

Comment: Получается, что так)

Comment: Спасибо! Выручила)